# compute signal given (Signal + Noise) and Noise in dBm

Tags: algorithm

Suppose we know (S + N) with x dBm and N with y dBm. Then S = 10 lg(10 ^ (x / 10) - 10 ^ (y / 10)) dBm. The problem is this computation necessitates float point, which is intensive on my embedded system. Is there any way to compute S (in dBm) more efficiently, preferably in integer only? Thanks in advance.

p.s.
S: signal
N: noise

Comment: You may precalculate functions and/or use fixed-point arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

Can you afford two 1D lookup tables? Write

```
10 lg(10 ^ (x / 10) - 10 ^ (y / 10)) = 10 lg(10 ^ (x / 10))     # lookup by x
                                     + 10 lg(1 - 10 ^ ((y - x) / 10))  # by y - x
```